# TFS build problem: missing assembly in test output folder

Tags: tfs, build, assemblies, testing

I am trying to integrate unit test cases with a TFS build in our new solution.  I've include the following configuration line in my TFSBuild.proj

```
<ItemGroup>
   <TestContainer Include="$(OutDir)\%2aTest.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Which I think is the correct configuration since I only have 1 test project.  However, when I do this, some dll is missing in the output folder of the test case, hence failing most of my test case.  Has anyone run into this problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either reference the project for the missing file from the test project, or add the missing file as a deployment item in your .testrunconfig file.

MSTest only copies the libraries it thinks it needs to to the test folder.

Comment: all the dlls are present when I run the test locally, but when I queue up a build on the TFS build server, it is missing a bunch of files.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you customized the output folder in the project properties? Team Build will override whatever is in those output folders, so if you're depending on that output directory that might be the issue. Also make sure that Team Build is building the configuration (Debug/Release) you think it is, and that all projects are set to build in that configuration.